# Android layout to bitmap rendering not working in an Activity context

Tags: android, layout, bitmap, rendering, appcompatactivity

I have the following code, that inflates a layout file and renders it to a bitmap.

If `parent` is an instance of an AppCompatActivity then everything works.
If I change the method signature to `createRouteBitmapFromLayout(Activity parent, ColorStateList color)` and call it from an activity that extends `android.app.Activity` then I get an empty bitmap of the correct size.

To recap, the only thing that changes is AppCompatActivity => Activity.

```
private static Bitmap createRouteBitmapFromLayout(AppCompatActivity parent, ColorStateList color) {
    View newViewElement = View.inflate(parent, R.layout.icon_node_topo_display, null);
    ((ImageView) newViewElement.findViewById(R.id.imagePin)).setImageTintList(color);

    newViewElement.measure(IconType.poiRouteIcon.measuredWidth, IconType.poiRouteIcon.measuredHeight);
    newViewElement.layout(0, 0, newViewElement.getMeasuredWidth(), newViewElement.getMeasuredHeight());

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newViewElement.getMeasuredWidth(), newViewElement.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.setDrawFilter(new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(0,Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG|Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    Drawable background = newViewElement.getBackground();

    if (background != null) {
        background.draw(canvas);
    }
    newViewElement.draw(canvas);
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, IconType.poiRouteIcon.iconPxWith, IconType.poiRouteIcon.iconPxHeight, true);
}
```

Thanks for the help.